# Changing the conjunctions (and, &, etc) in author-year citation call-outs

Tags: bibliographies

I am back again with a question of modifying the "harvard citation style" using agsm and natbib. I need to change the conjunction in my essay according to the the row "två författare" in this pdf https://www.hb.se/Global/HB%20-%20externt/BLR/Skriva%20och%20referera/Lathund_harvard2018.pdf

Recently I succeeded in changing the "and" conjunction to the corresponding swedish conjunction "och" using `\newcommand*{\harvardand}{och}`. Now, when writing `\cite{carlsson2007evidence} bidrar med bevis` the output in the pdf will be "Carlsson och Rooth bidrar med bevis", which is exactly what I want.

The problem arises when writing

```
[...] av människor inom samma samhälle\citep[s.~12]{edling2010ett}.
```

This yields

```
[...] av människor inom samma samhälle''(Edling och Liljeros 2010, s. 12).
```

What I want here is an `&` instead of `och`, as suggested in the pdf above.

So, my question is: How I am supposed to change `och` to `&` when using the `\citep{}` command, while still having `och` when using the `\cite{}` command?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to achieve is APA-style formatting of the conjunction used in citation call-outs: `&` in parenthetic-style citation call-outs and `och` (or `and`, or whatever the local language calls for) for text-style citation call-outs. Can you confirm that this impression is correct?

Comment: yes that is correct!

Comment: Are you familiar with the `apacite` bibliography style and the associated `apacite` citation management package? It does exactly what you're looking to do.

Comment: no! I have only used the agsm and IEEE bib style.

Comment: I've gone ahead and posted an answer to show how to use the `apacite` package along with Swedish-language adjustments.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like your bibliography must conform to the APA formatting guidelines -- of course, with suitable Swedish language adjustments -- I suggest you load the `apacite` package and bibliography style. If you load the `babel` package with the option `swedish`, Swedish language adjustments, such as the use of `och` instead of `and` as the conjunction, will be made automatically in the bibliography and in the citation call-outs.

Be sure to laod the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa` so that you can keep using `\citep` and `\citet` (or `\cite`).

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{EL:10,
   author = "Edling and Liljeros",
   title  = "Thoughts",
   year   = 2010,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\citet[s.~12]{EL:10}

\citep[s.~12]{EL:10}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try using this instead. Though I must say I'm feeling a bit confused since every single quick reference guide I've found for Harvard says that citations should look exactly as those you've shown for APA above. It is very confusing.

Comment: @VictorGaleano - Don't feel bad for feeling somewhat confused. The term "harvard" can have several meanings when applied to bibliographies and citation call-outs. To cut down on potential confusion, it's a good idea to call the style of the citation call-outs "author-year" rather than "harvard". The LaTeX package called `harvard` (and its `agsm` bib style) have no exclusive claim on implementing authoryear-style citation call-outs and formatted bibliographic entries.